# How to hide/delete underline input Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have input element in Angular Material:

```
<md-input-container>
<input type="text" mdInput placeholder="">
</md-input-container>
```

When input has focus it displays underline. How to hide or remove that?

Seem I need to set `null` for `underlineRef`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Update:**

Import `MdInputDirective`

```
import {MdInputDirective} from '@angular/material';
```

In compoent do following:

```
@ViewChild('input') input: MdInputDirective;

ngOnInit(){
  this.input.underlineRef.nativeElement.className = null;
}
```

In html, add the `#input` reference:

```
<md-input-container #input>
  <input  mdInput placeholder="Last 4 SSN">
</md-input-container>
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/XMhDIVBDup29sM8oi2dL?p=preview)

**Original:**

Try css:

```
::ng-deep .mat-input-underline {
    display: none;
}
```

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/hcdC2mP9f1v2ZyGH5gKI?p=preview)

Comment: But how to do that using property `underlineRef`?

Comment: hey , getting an error `Property 'underlineRef' does not exist on type 'MdInputDirective'`

Comment: Looking at you comment, I can't tell what code you have written/tried that's throwing/causing the error. There's a working plunker, you can compare your code with that. Or you can open a new SO question for your issue.

Comment: @Nehal, the Plunker is update to beta.7
the latest version is beta.12 which doesn't have MdInputDirective

Comment: What is `::ng-deep` ? Tried all CSS rules I could imagine, but nothing worked. Why is this working?

Comment: You can learn about ng-deep from angular.io's [page](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

Comment: I have to say... it's unbelivable that you have to import a directive for a bottom line that should be delt with with css... not in a good way

Answer (score 98):

I was playing a bit with the [`appearance`](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#MatFormFieldAppearance) property of `mat-form-field` and found that if you put a "none" value (or any other unsupported value), you will get clear input.

The code:

```html
  <mat-form-field appearance="none">
    <mat-label>"None" form field</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder">
  </mat-form-field>
```

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-syusfq?file=app%2Fform-field-appearance-example.html)  (edited from the official angular demo).

The original example can be found here: [Form field appearance variants](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/examples).

I admit, this is a little bit of a hack.

Comment: With ng-deep being deprecated, this is the best answer.

Comment: As per angular, use /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep only with emulated view encapsulation. I.e angular is not going to remove it.

Comment: With angularCompilerOptions.strictTemplates = true in tsconfig.json this leads to error TS2322: Type '"none"' is not assignable to type 'MatFormFieldAppearance'.

Comment: this works (on angular 9) but the height of the input gets increased

Comment: This no longer works with angular 15

Answer (score 53):

This worked for me:

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline {
    display: none;
}
```

Add it to the component's scss or css

Comment: works great, fyi it looks like `::ng-deep` is now [deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep), however this css worked for me without using it.

Comment: Traversing the link and its children they seem to say no replacement is proposed(!).

Very odd. At least it will almost certainly it will take years to be removed.

Thank-you for raising our attention about that.

Comment: Be careful, it is not the right answer. `::ng-deep` would apply to all Material Components that have this class. What you should do is add custom class to the component inside HTML and then reference it like this inside SCSS file. The correct answer should be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71959674/how-to-avoid-extra-mat-form-field-underline-in-angular-material

Answer (score 8):

```css
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline {
  display: none;
}
```

the above code will remove the default black underline

```css
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-ripple {
  display: none;
}
```

this will remove the on focus ripple effect

Answer (score 6):

```
This worked for me

.mat-form-field-appearance-legacy .mat-form-field-underline {
    height: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: This is the only CSS solution that worked for me (@angular/material 8.0)

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 5):

none of these worked for me except this

```
::ng-deep .mdc-line-ripple {
  display: none
}
```

as of **@angular/material 15.2.3**

Answer (score 4):

you can set your appearance to none in mat-form-field tag like this :

```
<mat-form-field class="header-search-form-field" appearance="none">
    <mat-label>search</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="add product/>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: This will not work when using strict mode. You will need to pass a value of MatFormFieldAppearance: material.angular.io/components/form-field/api

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `mat-form-field` instead of `md-input-container` and google-landed here, here are your two options.

1. Just comment out the `mat-form-field` and use your own styles.
2. See other appearance options available for [`mat-form-field` from the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#form-field-appearance-variants).

Answer (score 2):

The other answers didn't work for me, but this did:

```
md-input-container input {
        border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked without `::ng-deep`. Using Angular 6.1.10 as follows:

```
<form>
  <mat-form-field class="no-line">
    <input type="text"
                  matInput
                  field="label"
                  [matAutocomplete]="auto"
                  [formControl]="formControl"/>
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
          {{ food.label}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

---

```
.no-line .mat-form-field-underline {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just set `appearance="none"` inside the tag

```
<mat-form-field style="width:40px" appearance="none"> </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: This will not work when using strict mode. You will need to pass a value of MatFormFieldAppearance: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api

Comment: How exactly  pass a value of MatFormFieldAppearance ?

Answer (score 1):

Lots of good answers here, but here's one I found useful, did not need ::ng-deep or anything like that. Simply add this to your global styles.scss file. Use on any form fields you don't want an underline.

```
.mat-form-field.no-underline .mat-form-field-underline {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried every solution but nothing worked for me so I did this little trick using only the CSS. Also if you want to hide it for a specific element only than add a custom class with it.

```
    .mat-form-field-underline {
    display: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove underline from a specific field use ng-deep css with #id of the field

```
 #IdOfControl ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline  {
      display: none;
    }
```