# Toggle underline for mat-form-field matInput on and off on click

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

Is it possible to toggle the underline for a matInput of a mat-form-field on and off using either CSS or backend Typescript?

I have seen something such as **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45556972/how-to-hide-delete-underline-input-angular-material)** which shows it can be ***removed*** with css such as:

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline {
    display: none;
}
```

But I am unsure whether this can be implemented within an **`[ngClass]`**
 to toggle it?

The question also shows that it can be done programatically, however I am unaware of if this is reversible, and also I am using material design with the prefix `mat` rather than `md`...

```
@ViewChild('input') input: MdInputDirective;

ngOnInit(){
  this.input.underlineRef.nativeElement.className = null;
}
```

Here is my [blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-underline-toggle)

Answer (score 2):

> You can apply/remove a class based on some condition in your component
>   (use boolean for example). see [ngClass] or [class.class-name] for
>   usage.

the above comment can help you half.... 
the underline class is set automaticaly by angular material.

```
<div class="mat-form-field-underline"><span class="mat-form-field-ripple"></span></div>
```

A workaround of this issue is to add a class in the **mat-form-field**

```
<mat-form-field [ngClass]="{'form-field--read':field.readOnly }" > <input matInput .........  /> </mat-form-field>
```

and combine it with scss/css:

```
  ::ng-deep .form-field--read .mat-form-field-underline {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the CSS class that enables the underline to be removed, but my question is how can I use something like this to toggle the line on and off? Would it be possible to use `::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline` within an `[ngClass]`?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your mat-form-field:

```
[ngClass]="{'mat-form-field-invalid': errorExists}"
```

errorExists is a boolean that represents whether there is currently an error or not. If you already have a variable for the error, you can do something like "error != " instead of `errorExists`

Answer (score -1):

You can apply/remove a class based on some condition in your component (use boolean for example). see `[ngClass]` or `[class.class-name]` for usage.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9w1w4b

Comment: Is there any chance you could provide a more specific example?

Comment: You can update css using given classes. See the CSS file in the blitz. I've added underline when `one-class` is applied.

Comment: I am passing hardcoded strings `green` and `red` from the HTML, you can update the condition is the component itself and check for them in the `[ngClass]`