# How to avoid extra mat-form-field-underline in Angular material

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am having an issue finding why I get an extra mat-form-field-underline when using a component.

My page uses this markup:

```
<mat-form-field class="col-md-6">
        <app-mat-select-all 
            [data]="tractList$"
            formControlName="tractList"
            fieldName="name"
            [multiselect]=true
            labelText="Tract List"
            idField="guid"
            >
        </app-mat-select-all>
</mat-form-field>
```

And my custom component has the following template code

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>{{labelText}}</mat-label>
    <mat-select  #select [multiple]="multiselect" [formControl]="selectField" >
      <div class="select-all">
          <mat-checkbox *ngIf="multiselect" [(ngModel)]="allSelected"
                          [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                          [indeterminate]="isIndeterminate()"
                          [checked]="isChecked()" 
                          (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                          (change)="toggleAllSelection($event)">{{text}}</mat-checkbox>
      </div>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of data" [value]="item[idField]">
        {{item[fieldName]}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    </form>
```

And it looks like this on the rendered page

[image]

When I go and add the following line to my parent style sheet all mat-form-field-underlines are gone which is not what I want. If I go and remove the mat-form-field in my custom component I only get one line but then the alignment of the mat-form-field-underline is off with the other components on page. So I need to find a way to only target the 2nd underline to be able to remove.

```scss
    ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline {
        display: none;
    }
```

Here is a stackblitz sample which demonstrate this issue of the 2nd underline [StackBlitz Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t2mbpo?file=src/app/mat-select/mat-select.component.ts)

Here is the code when i inspect it and it seems that for some reason there is a mat-form-field inside a mat-form-field. Not sure why ?

```
<mat-form-field _ngcontent-jtb-c709="" class="mat-form-field col-md-6 ng-tns-c393-17 mat-primary mat-form-field-appearance-legacy mat-form-field-can-float mat-form-field-hide-placeholder"><div class="mat-form-field-wrapper ng-tns-c393-17"><div class="mat-form-field-flex ng-tns-c393-17"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "0"
}--><div class="mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c393-17"><app-mat-select-all _ngcontent-jtb-c709="" formcontrolname="tractList" fieldname="name" labeltext="Tract List" idfield="guid" _nghost-jtb-c804="" ng-reflect-field-name="name" ng-reflect-label-text="Tract List" ng-reflect-id-field="guid" ng-reflect-name="tractList" ng-reflect-form-control-name="tractList" class="ng-tns-c393-17 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-reflect-multiselect="true" ng-reflect-data="[object Object],[object Object"><form _ngcontent-jtb-c804="" novalidate="" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><mat-form-field _ngcontent-jtb-c804="" class="mat-form-field ng-tns-c393-18 mat-primary mat-form-field-type-mat-select mat-form-field-appearance-legacy mat-form-field-can-float mat-form-field-has-label mat-form-field-hide-placeholder ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><div class="mat-form-field-wrapper ng-tns-c393-18"><div class="mat-form-field-flex ng-tns-c393-18"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "0"
}--><div class="mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c393-18"><mat-select _ngcontent-jtb-c804="" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="none" aria-haspopup="true" class="mat-select ng-tns-c500-19 ng-tns-c393-18 ng-star-inserted mat-select-empty mat-select-multiple ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-reflect-multiple="true" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]" aria-labelledby="mat-form-field-label-19 mat-select-value-15" id="mat-select-14" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false" aria-required="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-invalid="false"><div cdk-overlay-origin="" class="mat-select-trigger ng-tns-c500-19"><div class="mat-select-value ng-tns-c500-19" ng-reflect-ng-switch="true" id="mat-select-value-15"><span class="mat-select-placeholder mat-select-min-line ng-tns-c500-19 ng-star-inserted"></span><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "true"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "false"
}--></div><div class="mat-select-arrow-wrapper ng-tns-c500-19"><div class="mat-select-arrow ng-tns-c500-19"></div></div></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-offset-y": "0"
}--></mat-select><span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper ng-tns-c393-18"><label class="mat-form-field-label ng-tns-c393-18 mat-empty mat-form-field-empty ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-disabled="true" id="mat-form-field-label-19" ng-reflect-ng-switch="true" for="mat-select-14" aria-owns="mat-select-14"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "false"
}--><mat-label _ngcontent-jtb-c804="" class="ng-tns-c393-18 ng-star-inserted">Tract List</mat-label><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "true"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--></label><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--></span></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "0"
}--></div><div class="mat-form-field-underline ng-tns-c393-18 ng-star-inserted"><span class="mat-form-field-ripple ng-tns-c393-18"></span></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div class="mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper ng-tns-c393-18" ng-reflect-ng-switch="hint"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "error"
}--><div class="mat-form-field-hint-wrapper ng-tns-c393-18 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages ng-star-inserted" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%);"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": ""
}--><div class="mat-form-field-hint-spacer ng-tns-c393-18"></div></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "hint"
}--></div></div></mat-form-field></form></app-mat-select-all><span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper ng-tns-c393-17"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--></span></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "0"
}--></div><div class="mat-form-field-underline ng-tns-c393-17 ng-star-inserted"><span class="mat-form-field-ripple ng-tns-c393-17"></span></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div class="mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper ng-tns-c393-17" ng-reflect-ng-switch="hint"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "error"
}--><div class="mat-form-field-hint-wrapper ng-tns-c393-17 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages ng-star-inserted" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%);"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": ""
}--><div class="mat-form-field-hint-spacer ng-tns-c393-17"></div></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "hint"
}--></div></div></mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do this:

```scss
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline {
  display: none;
}
```

That would apply to all Material Components that have this class. What you should do is add custom class to the component inside HTML and then reference it like this inside SCSS file:

```html
<mat-form-field class="custom-class">
  ...
</mat-form-field>
```

```scss
::ng-deep .custom-class .mat-form-field-underline {
  display: none;
}
```

Now, only that component will be affected by `::ng-deep` override.

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4e6dwg?file=src/app/app.component.css)

Comment: That causes a bunch of new issues as the underline of the custom component is no longer lined up with the standard mat-select components on the page.

Comment: If you look at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t2mbpo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmat-select%2Fmat-select.component.html it shows the issue, if you remove the mat-form the alignment will be gone as well as a lot of formatting

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it?

Comment: Thanks that did the trick without losing a bunch of styles

Comment: With the new MDC design, it's the `mdc-line-ripple` you need to hide.

Comment: It works only with ::ng-deep which is deprecated :(